# Extract number that is on the 2d/3rd line from a match

Tags: php, regex

I have unfortunately lost some important financial records from my database due to technical issues and therefore I am required to go through my invoices which are all available online.

There are probably thousands of transactions so I thought the smartest thing to do would be to create a program that will be able to extract transaction values I need.

Once the pdfs are converted into plain text the structure seems to break and I have something that looks like this mess

```
Debit card payment to site.com
Germany
on 01 May 3.63
Debit card payment to  site Germany
on 01 May 3.63
Debit card payment to site.Com
Germany
on 01 May 3.63
Debit card payment to Paypal *Xiao
Ref:- 23948 0000000000 32.98
```

From the above transactions I would like to grab payments, 3.63, 3.63, 3.63 and put them all in an array.

Every transaction starts with the word Debit and end with the amount.

I am trying to figure out my expenses and since I only buy from one supplier (lets call the supplier 'site') I only need to extract the payment amount I made to this one entity

The payment value is at the end of the every transaction 
I think my best option is to use php and regex
(note: 'site' has 3 different name variations site, site.com, site.Com)

I honestly don't know much about regex but below is my attempt which has not got me far

```
preg_match(
    "/(Debit card payment to site.com).*?(([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]{2})?)/",    
    $text, 
    $results
);
```

The above regex does not work with line breaks and probably does not extract the first occurrence after the search term.

I am lost, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every line with ammount starts with "on "?

Comment: @dminones Sorry every line starts with the string 'Debit'

Comment: To make the regexp go across line boundaries, use the `s` modifier.

Comment: @mk_89 but in your example seems like the lines from the original pdf are breaking up in more lines, isn't?

Comment: Transactions get broken up in to 2 or 3 lines, but the transactions I require break up into 3

Comment: I see, what I meant is that if the 3rd line from every transaction starts with "on" the problem is much simpler 'cause you could filter this lines and take the final number

Comment: @dminones I see what you mean, no this is not always the case because transactions are broken up in to pages their is other text that can occur between transactions, I just need to extract the first money amount after a specific string which in this case is 'site'

Comment: I updated my answer to match your requirements, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will be the best option assuming `site.com` (case-insensitive) is the only key you need to match against prior to obtaining the value.

**Regex**

```
(?:site(?:\.com)?[\s\w^]*)\s(\d+\.\d{2})
```

[**REGEX101**](https://regex101.com/r/wZ8vG6/4)

**Example**

```
$re = "/(?:site(?:\\.com)?[\\s\\w^]*)\\s(\\d+\\.\\d{2})/i"; 
$str = "Debit card payment to site.com\nGermany\non 01 May 3.63\nDebit card payment to  site Germany\non 01 May 3.63\nDebit card payment to site.Com\nGermany\non 01 May 3123.63\nDebit card payment to Paypal *Xiao\nRef:- 23948 0000000000 32.98"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

***Edit*** I really need more coffee, none the less I updated the above (hopefully for the last time)...

Comment: My question is long so I can understand why you have misunderstood something, I only want transactions from site or site.com or site.Com, this returns all transaction amounts including the unwanted paypal transaction

Comment: I've tested it, it doesn't quiet work but I feel like you're close, it captures site.com and site.Com values but not 'site'

`(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => site.com
Germany
on 01 May 3.63
            [1] => site.Com
Germany
on 01 May 3.63
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => site.com
Germany
on 01 May
            [1] => site.Com
Germany
on 01 May
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.63
            [1] => 3.63
        )

)`

Comment: I hate to both you again, it looks good, but just one tiny issue, their may be payments that are are larger, such as 129.90, 12.3, these get converted into 9.90 and 2.3 (sorry about this, I'm useless at regex)

Comment: @mk_89 I have updated it to allow for longer whole numbers in the value

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know I'm being a pain but another issue has come into the mix,  there are lines where there may be two numbers per statement e.g. `3.63 120`,  is there a way to make sure that I only get the first number, I promise this will be the last thing I ask of you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, bingo.

```
    $regex = "/\s([0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]+)/";

$text = "Debit card payment to site.com
Germany
on 01 May 3.63
Debit card payment to  site Germany
on 01 May 3.63
Debit card payment to site.Com
Germany
on 01 May 3.63
Debit card payment to Paypal *Xiao
Ref:- 23948 0000000000 32.98";

preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);

$result = $matches[1];
```

I've tested it, it works perfect and it should work for you.

`$result` is that array you need.

Comment: Doesnt work completely as it need to check for a numerical value (\d+) followed by a `.` followed by exactly two numerical values (\d{2}), see [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/lC5qE9/1)

Comment: what error you see or what result you see? have you tried `print_r($result);` to see results?